# Changing form border style to none, causes error when using linear gradient brush

Tags: c#, forms, border, linear-gradients

I am having an issue with a Windows forms application. I had to change the configurations to handle an Access violation exception.

Anyways I'm essentially making a program that pops up in the bottom right corner like a notification. It's not the whole program, but something I will be integrating. I am having some issues with the LinearGradientBrush class. I noticed my window was moving while it tried to paint the background through the AccessViolationExcetption, so I made a boolean value in the OnPaintBackgroundMethod to make note of when the drawing process was going and make sure the window doesn't move while the function is running. This seemed to fix the issue. Except, when I further customized the form design by taking away the border in the FormBorderStyle panel the issue returned. I have no idea why this would cause any trouble and have looked everywhere for a solution to no avail. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

```
 <configuration>
 <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
 </startup>
 <runtime>
  <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
 </runtime>
 </configuration>


 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace NewToasterNotifier
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer timer;
    private int startPosX, startPosY, beginning, middle, speed, paintCount;
    private bool rectangleIsDrawing;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TopMost = true;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 20;

        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        //This divides the window into three sections
        //The beginning is first used as the scalar amaount of each interval
        beginning = Height / 3;
        //middle is where the middle section ends
        middle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - 2 * beginning;
        //and now beginnning is where the beginning section ends
        //the true begginnning section starts at the screen.height
        beginning = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - beginning;
        speed = 0;
    }
    //On load of the form
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        startPosX = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Width;
        startPosY = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
        SetDesktopLocation(startPosX, startPosY);
        base.OnLoad(e);
        timer.Start();
        paintCount = 0;
    }
    //Override of the onPaintbackground, which allows us to make a different background on windows forms
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        rectangleIsDrawing = true;
        paintCount++;
        Console.Write("\n Painting... " + paintCount.ToString());
        //implements a linear gradient to the background
        using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle,
                                                          Color.Gray,
                                                          Color.Black,
                                                          90F))
        {
            paintThatShiz(e, brush);
        }
    }
    //linear gradient needs to change on resize
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
        base.OnResize(e);
    }
    //debugging purposes
    private void paintThatShiz(PaintEventArgs e, LinearGradientBrush brush)
    {


        try { e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle); }
        catch (AccessViolationException x)
        {
            Console.Write("No, no, no!!!!!");
            paintThatShiz(e, brush);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException z)
        {
            Console.Write("This is ridiculous, \n");
            Console.Write(z.StackTrace);
            paintThatShiz(e, brush);
        }
        rectangleIsDrawing = false;

    }
    //called every 10ms for window to animate and stops when done
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rectangleIsDrawing) { return; }

        Console.Write("\n Starting to move");
        // this if block is for the swing animation
        //in the beginning it speeds up
        if (startPosY > beginning)
        {
            speed++;
        }//in the end it slows down
        else if (startPosY < middle)
        {
            if (speed > 1)
            {
                speed--;
            }
        }
        //in the middle it stays constant
        Console.Write(speed.ToString() + " ");
        startPosY -= speed;
        //Stops when done
        if (startPosY < Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Height)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        } // checks again to see if rectangle is drawing before accessing window location data
        else {
            if (rectangleIsDrawing) {
                startPosY += speed;
                return; 
            }
            SetDesktopLocation(startPosX, startPosY);
        }



    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, dont't use Windows Forms for custom looking windows. Especially the Linear Gradient Tool, which is very buggy and really just a hack for drawing a rectangle on top of the form. I started using WPF and it's amazing. Don't mean to toot my own horn, but I hope this steers people clear of using Windows Forms for such reasons.